# flutter project folders in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

im new to android studio and i want to see my porject folder parts like the first time i created under each other on the left part not like this:
please show me (by picture in case of your kindness)what settings and where should i change to.
thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAMmY.png)
this is what i see/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtCjm.png)
i dont want to see my folders like this.by clicking on project name...

Comment: android studio dolphin 2021. is inistalled..

Comment: In the left pane, it says Android. That's why you only see the Android part of it. click on the down arrow and select Project. Then you will be able to see the Flutter structure.

Answer (score 1):

1:First open android setting.
2: Then click on setting icon
3:Click on "Always open" check,

[click on setting icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKph.png)

[then click on "Always "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjMGY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).